# How Tkinter font.families() function gets a list of available font?

Tags: python, tkinter, fonts

I'm making GUI application using Tkinter and I'm using tkinter.font.families() for making pull down list of selecting fonts.

Now, I'm  wondering how this function works
I tried reading the code but I can't understand it because of my lack of enough knowledge...

```py
def families(root=None, displayof=None):
    "Get font families (as a tuple)"
    if not root:
        root = tkinter._default_root
    args = ()
    if displayof:
        args = ('-displayof', displayof)
    return root.tk.splitlist(root.tk.call("font", "families", *args))
```

This is a code of the function(https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/c4928fc1a853f3f84e2b4ec1253d0349137745e5/Lib/tkinter/font.py#L180).

my qeustion is

- What is the meaning of `args = ('-displayof', displayof)`?
- Where does tk.call() function came from?(I can't find this function in Tk class)
- How does `tk.call("font", "families", *args)` function works?

Thank you for reading my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is the meaning of args = ('-displayof', displayof)?

Tkinter is a small python wrapper around a tcl interepreter which has the tk package installed. All of the actual work of creating widgets, querying fonts, etc, is done by the tcl/tk libraries.

Tcl/tk commands use a leading dash to represent an option name, and the option is typically followed by a value. This code is preparing to call a tcl function, so it is building up a list of arguments required by tcl.

In this specific case, it's adding the `-displayof` option if the `displayof` argument was passed to the function.

> Where does tk.call() function came from?

It comes from a C-based library. It is defined in a file named [_tkinter.c](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Modules/_tkinter.c). More specifically, it's the function `Tkapp_Call`. It is a small wrapper that allows python to execute commands within an embedded tcl interpreter.

> How does tk.call("font", "families", *args) function works?

The tk library has a command named [font](https://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl8.6/TkCmd/font.htm). From within a tcl interpreter you would call it with something like this:

```
font families
```

The code `tk.call("font", "families", *args)` is simply sending that command to the tcl interpreter.

The underlying tcl/tk library has platform-specific functions for dealing with fonts. See [tkMacOSXFont.c](https://core.tcl-lang.org/tk/artifact/9856353e9cf891cc), [tkUnixFont.c](https://core.tcl-lang.org/tk/artifact/7ef76f8f54e480e8), and [tkWinFont.c](https://core.tcl-lang.org/tk/artifact/2de5ad65afd4adca).